# How do I make a webpart's settings configurable in Sharepoint?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I am  publishing a portal template.

I want to develop a WebPart and make some settings configurable (just like we can configure parameters for a console application in app.config)

For example, authorized users could set parameters of WebPart in Edit Page (from browser based UI interface), then `Select -> Modify WebPart` properties, or edit parameters in SharePoint Designer.

The parameters would be application specific parameters.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make your properties on the webpart and add attributes like so....

```
[WebBrowsable(true),Category("Calendar Setup"),
 WebDisplayName("Starting Date Column"),
 WebDescription("column that contains item starting date"),
 Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

You should check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174(office.11).aspx) for a full list and a good article on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Check and see of this helps

[Writing custom editors for Sharepoint 2007 and ASP.NET 2.0 WebParts](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006/05/19/writing-custom-editors-for-sharepoint-2007-and-aspnet-20-webparts.aspx)